# alternate color gridview rows based on change of cell value asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

**1 item 

1 item**
 
2 item
2 item
**3 item**
4 item
4 item
**5 item**

I have a gridview bound to a datasource.  I want to change the color of the rows based on the GROUPING of the first column. I do not know what the values of the column will be, but basically I need to switch from one color to the other color when the value in that column changes.  (I used bold to show what I mean) Once again **I don't know the value in that column, so I can't just say "if it equals 1 then do this**" - I know how to do that. :))  So just switch the row color from blue to red each time the value in column one changes.  (i.e. red, red, blue, blue, red, blue, blue, red per the example above)  Thanks for any suggestions.  (I'm a VB person, but can manage to translate code if need be.  Thanks again)

Comment: Probably going to have to do this in the HTML/jaavscript as opposed to the vb.net. Set up listener for whatever these items are being rendered to and set the colors as needed

Answer (score 3):

I found the following (cept in C#, but here it is in VB)  This works. :) I can setup the css for the two classes and works out fine.  Every time the item in column 1 changes it changes the class on the row.

```
Dim currentClass As String = "alternateDataRow"
Dim currentGroup As String = ""

Protected Sub gvPayrollRecords_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvPayrollRecords.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim rowGroup As String = e.Row.Cells(1).Text

        If rowGroup <> currentGroup Then
            If currentClass = "datarow" Then
                currentClass = "alternateDataRow"
            Else
                currentClass = "datarow"
            End If

            currentGroup = rowGroup
        End If

        e.Row.CssClass = currentClass

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How could i do the same but for c#?