# Setting gridview row background colour by alternating by row data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound, alternating

I have a GridView where I am listing values for client companies. Take for example the grid listed the company name and a value. I want to give a *light gray* background color to all **Company 1**'s rows, then *white* for **Company 2**'s rows and then back to *light grey* for **Company 3**'s rows and alternating like so.

---

Company 1  12

Company 1  15

Company 1  18

---

Company 2  25

Company 2  78

Company 2  109

---

Company 3  66

Company 3  1

---

Can this be done simply in the `_RowDataBound` event, and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use this question

[alternate color gridview rows based on change of cell value asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288908/alternate-color-gridview-rows-based-on-change-of-cell-value-asp-net)

to create my own solution in c#. So basically, create two global variables. Then within the _RowDatabound do the below

```
int customerCompanyID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["IRPCustomerID"]);

 if (customerCompanyID != this._trafficSourceGridCurrentCompanyID)
            {
                if (this._trafficSourceGridGroupingCssClass == 
"BackGround2")
                {
                    this._trafficSourceGridGroupingCssClass = "BackGround1";
                }
                else
                {
                    this._trafficSourceGridGroupingCssClass = "BackGround2";
                }

                this._trafficSourceGridCurrentCompanyID = customerCompanyID;                    
            }

            e.Row.CssClass = _trafficSourceGridGroupingCssClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `RowDataBound` event you can do something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // check if its not a header or footer row
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // get value from first cell of gridview
        string companyName = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;

        switch (companyName)
        {
            case "Company 1":
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                break;
            case "Company 2":
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                break;
            case "Company 3":
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```